# Override WordPress wp_mail function

Tags: wordpress

I know there is a filter for `wp_mail`, but I don't want to only change arguments. I'm trying to reimplement `wp_mail` with a custom RESTful API, so I need to change the functionality of `wp_mail`.
How can I do that?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your function again in theme's `functions.php`.

```
function wp_mail(){
    echo 'TEST';
}
```

Comment: I want to override it for entire wordpress.